# Finding two non-congruent right-angle triangles

Tags: geometry, number-theory, elliptic-curves, pythagorean-triples

The map $g: B \to A, \ (x,y) \mapsto \left(\dfrac {x^2 - 25} y, \dfrac {10x} y, \dfrac {x^2 + 25} y \right)$ is a bijection where $A = \{ (a,b,c) \in \Bbb Q ^3 : a^2 + b^2 = c^2, \ ab = 10 \}$ and $B = \{ (x,y) \in \Bbb Q ^2 : y^2 = x^3 - 25x, \ y \ne 0 \}$.

---

Given the *Pythagorean triple*,

$$
\begin{aligned}
a&=\frac {x^2 - 25} y\\
b&=\frac {10x} y\\
c&=\frac {x^2 + 25} y
\end{aligned}
$$
so $a^2+b^2 = c^2$ and $y\neq 0$. We wish to set its *area* $G = 5$. Thus,

$$G = \frac{1}{2}ab = \frac{1}2 \frac {10x} y \frac {(x^2 - 25)} y  = 5$$

Or simply,

$$x^3-25x = y^2\tag1$$

Can you help find two non-congruent right-angled triangles that have rational side lengths and area equal to $5$?

Comment: How are the first part of the question and the second part related?

Comment: there are two points where P(-4,6) and Q(0,0) on the elliptic curve y^2=x^3-25x

Comment: I am completely lost. Are we missing something in the question?

Comment: @G.Sassatelli: Don't you think the set $A$ describes right-angled triangles of the required type? Given the first part, the question about triangles is thus reduced to finding rational points on the elliptic curve (other than the 2-torsion points).

Comment: Have you tried what the point doubling formula does to $P=(-4,6)$? Or just adding one of the points $(0,0)$ or $(\pm5,0)$ to $P$?

Comment: Please reopen this question. I think that it makes a lot of sense now and people are forced to provide real answers in comments.

Comment: A [very closely related question](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1290878/11619). The comments to its answer give at least one other rational point on the elliptic curve. Can you show that $g$ is bijective?

Comment: Thanks a million Jyrki.. these are really helpful.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen: I tried to ascertain what the OP wanted. I hope I interpreted it correctly since his post was a bit unclear from the start.

Answer (score 3):

*Update*: It turns out that for rational $a,b,c$, if,

$$a^2+b^2 = c^2$$

$$\tfrac{1}{2}ab = n$$

then $n$ is a *[congruent number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Congruent_number)*. The first few are $n = 5, 6, 7, 13, 14, 15, 20, 21, 22,\dots$

---

After all the terminology, I guess all the OP wanted was to solve $(1)$. He asks, "... *find **two** non-congruent right-angled triangles that have rational side lengths and area equal to 5*".

We'll define [congruence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Congruence_(geometry)) as *"... two figures are congruent if they have the same shape **and** size.*" Since we want *non-congruent*, then two such right triangles are,

$$a,b,c = \frac{3}{2},\;\frac{20}{3},\;\frac{41}{6}$$

$$a,b,c = \frac{1519}{492},\;\frac{4920}{1519},\;\frac{3344161}{747348}$$

However, since the elliptic curve,

$$x^3-25x = y^2\tag1$$

has an *infinite* number of rational points, then there is no need to stop at just two. Two small solutions to $(1)$ are $x_1 = 5^2/2^2 =u^2/v^2$ and $x_2 = 45$. We can use the first one as an easy way to generate an infinite subset of solutions. Let, $x =u^2/v^2$, so,

$$\frac{u^2}{v^6}(u^4-25v^4) = y^2$$

or just,

$$u^4-25v^4 = w^2\tag2$$

a curve also discussed in [the post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1290878/) cited by J. Lahtonen. Here is a theorem by Lagrange. Given an initial solution $u^4+bv^4 = w^2$, then further ones are,

$$X^4+bY^4 = Z^2$$

where,

$$X,Y,Z = u^4-bv^4,\; 2uvw,\; (u^4+bv^4)^2 + 4 b u^4 v^4$$

Thus, using Lagrange's theorem recursively, we have the infinite sequence,

$$u,v,w = 5,\;2,\;15$$

$$u,v,w = 41,\;12,\;1519$$

$$u,v,w = 3344161,\; 1494696,\; 535583225279$$

and so on.