# On Diophantine equations of the form $x^4-n^2y^4=z^2$

Tags: number-theory, diophantine-equations, systems-of-equations, elliptic-curves, quadratic-forms

(*This complements the [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1964708/4781) on* $x^4+m^2y^4=z^2$.)

A subset of solutions to,
$$(x^2-101y^2)(x^2+101y^2)=z_1^2\tag1$$
also solve,
$$x^2-101y^2=z_2^2\tag2$$
$$x^2+101y^2=z_3^2\tag3$$
For example, we have $x,y$ ***only*** for eq. $(1)$ $$x=2125141,\;y=63050,\;z_1=4498341355119$$
But since $n=101$ is a *congruent number*, all three can be solved, the smallest being,

$$x = 2015242462949760001961\\y = 118171431852779451900$$

> **Q:** In general, if for some $n$ the Diophantine 
>   $$(x^2-ny^2)(x^2+ny^2)=z_1^2$$
>   has solutions (infinitely many since an elliptic curve is involved), does that necessarily mean a subset  solve the simultaneous 
>   $$x^2-ny^2=z_2^2\\
> x^2+ny^2=z_3^2$$
>   as well?

Comment: I just realized this is also part of [an older question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1576861/on-p2-nq2-z2-p2-nq2-t2-and-the-congruent-number-problem) I asked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes: The pair of equations $x^2 - n y^2 = z_2^2$, $x^2 + n y^2 = z_3^2$
defines a genus 1 curve in $\mathbb P^3$. Since it has obvious rational
points (with $y = 0$), it is an elliptic curve, and the map to the
original curve $x^4 - n^2 y^4 = z_1^2$ given by setting $z_1 = z_2 z_3$
is a 2-isogeny (when choosing the origins in a compatible way).
So the groups of rational points on the two elliptic curves have the
same rank; in particular, if one is infinite, then so is the other.

Comment: [Please](http://math.stackexchange.com/contact) merge [your](http://math.stackexchange.com/users/378836) two [accounts](http://math.stackexchange.com/users/378913).