# Rational solutions of $x^2 - 5 = y^2$, $x^2 + 5 = z^2$

Tags: number-theory

Find all rational solutions $(x,y,z)$ of:
$$\begin{cases} x^2 - 5 = y^2 \\ x^2 + 5 = z^2 \end{cases}$$

I was told that this problem is given to Fibonacci by the king at that time. He found one solution is $\big ( \frac{41}{12}, \frac{31}{12}, \frac{49}{12} \big )$.

Can we know how Fibonacci found this solution?
Can we actually solve this system of equation?

Comment: I think we should use diophantine equations

Comment: Yes, I tried to "integer-ize" the problem by setting $x = \frac{a}{b}, y = \frac{c}{d}, z = \frac{e}{f}$, but it looks so messy that way.

Comment: For a small start to a large subject, please see the Wikipedia article on [congruent numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Congruent_number)

Comment: This is exercise number $5$ of the first chapter in Koblitz book "Introduction to Elliptic curves and Modular forms", dealing with congruent numbers.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1584485/what-are-all-the-concordant-forms-n-such-that-a2b2-c2-a2nb2-d2-f

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1576861/on-p2-nq2-z2-p2-nq2-t2-and-the-congruent-number-problem

Comment: See also [this MSE question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1558413/finding-two-non-congruent-right-angle-triangles).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because $n=5$ is a congruent number, there exists a rational $v=x^2$, such that $v\pm 5$ is a positive rational square. All positive rational solutions are in bijection to the rational sides $X,Y,Z$ of a right triangle with area $5$; in general the correspondence is given as follows (for a squarefree congruent number $n$):
$$
(X,Y,Z)\mapsto v=(Z/2)^2,\; 
$$
and conversely 
$$
v\mapsto X:=\sqrt{v+n}-\sqrt{v-n},\; Y:=\sqrt{v+n}+\sqrt{v-n},\;Z:=2\sqrt{v}.
$$
In particular, $n$ is congruent if and only if there exists a rational $v=x^2$ such that $v\pm n$ are squares of rational numbers.

To find all rational solutions, a bijection to certain rational points on the elliptic curve $E_n:y^2=x^3-n^2x$ can be used. The elliptic curve $E_5$ for $n=5$ has rank $1$, and all rational points on it are known. Its Mordell-Weil group is given by $E_5(\mathbb{Q})\equiv \mathbb{Z}_2\times \mathbb{Z}_2\times \mathbb{Z}$, generated by the points $(0,0)$, $(5,0)$ and $(-4,6)$. Take for example $P=(-4,6)$. Then $2P=((\frac{41}{12})^2,-\frac{62279}{1728})$. Let $x=(\frac{41}{12})^2$. Then $x-5=(\frac{31}{12})^2$
and $x+5=(\frac{49}{12})^2$. This gives your first solution
$$
\frac{41}{12},\; \frac{31}{12},\; \frac{49}{12}.
$$
We obtain infinitely many others (all in fact) the same way.

Reference (among many others): K. Conrad's [article](http://www.math.rug.nl/~top/congnumber.pdf).

Answer (score 0):

Here's another approach:

$$\frac{{\left( {m}^{4}+{g}^{4}\right) }^{2}}{4\,{g}^{2}\,{m}^{2}}\pm\left( {m}^{2}-{g}^{2}\right) \,\left( {m}^{2}+{g}^{2}\right) =\frac{{\left( {m}^{4}\pm2\,{g}^{2}\,{m}^{2}-{g}^{4}\right) }^{2}}{4\,{g}^{2}\,{m}^{2}}$$

If $$\left( {m}^{2}-{g}^{2}\right) \,\left( {m}^{2}+{g}^{2}\right) =5\,{a}^{2}$$

For example: $$m=3,g=1$$