# Is it true that $n = 2t^2-2$ for even $t$ is a congruent number?

Tags: number-theory, systems-of-equations, quadratic-forms, pythagorean-triples

[This post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1844034/for-which-n-can-a-nb-c-and-b-c-d-be-pythagorean-triples) asks for $m$ such that the simultaneous Pythagorean triples,
$$a^2+m^2b^2 = c^2\\b^2+c^2 = d^2\tag1$$
have solutions. Will Jagy found an infinite family given by,

$$m = 2t^2-2 = 0, 6, 16, 30, 48, 70, 96, 126, \dots$$

where,

$$\begin{aligned}
a &= -1 + 9 t^2 - 12 t^4 + 4 t^6\\ b &=  -2 t + 4 t^3\\c &=  -1 + t^2 - 4 t^4 + 4 t^6\\ d  &=  1 + t^2 - 4 t^4 + 4 t^6
\end{aligned}$$

---

The values $m=6,30,70$ were faintly familiar, as I had posted about *[congruent numbers](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CongruentNumber.html)* before. (See [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1576861/on-p2-nq2-z2-p2-nq2-t2-and-the-congruent-number-problem) and [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1558413/finding-two-non-congruent-right-angle-triangles).) A number $n$ is congruent if there is a solution to the simultaneous,

$$p^2 + nq^2 = r^2\\
p^2 - nq^2 = s^2\tag2$$

> **Q1:** Is it true that an infinite family of congruent numbers is given by,
>   $$n = 2(2v)^2-2 = 6,30,70,126,\dots$$

**P.S.** [A003273](https://oeis.org/A003273) gives a list of congruent numbers $N<10000$ and all $n$ of that form are there.

> **Q2:** If indeed true, what is the connection between systems $(1)$ and $(2)$?

Answer (score 2):

(*This is a partial answer*.)

After some persistence and effort, I managed to find a partial answer. It can be proven that
$$n = 2t^2-2$$
is a *congruent number* for infinitely many $t$ (odd or even).

**Proof:** If,

$$n = 2(v^2\pm3)^2-2$$

then,

$$p^2+nq^2=r^2\\p^2-nq^2 = s^2$$

has the simple solution,

$$\begin{aligned}p &=v^4\pm4v^2+8
\\q &=2v\end{aligned}$$